# PlantUml . Placing classes on canvas page

Tags: plantuml, erd

I have the ER Diagram with classes and connections placed inappropriately. Connections and multiplicity are overlaped and the diagram seem a little bit streched.

```
@startuml

' hide the spot
hide circle

' avoid problems with angled crows feet
skinparam linetype ortho

entity Воронка{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity Должность{
  ID <<PK>>
  Код должности
  Наименование
  ID Воронки <<FK, UNIQUE>>
}

entity Гражданство{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity Регион{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity Образование{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity Языки{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity "Опыт работы"{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity "Тип занятости"{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование 
}

entity Похожие_должности{
  ID Должности
  ID Похожей должности
}

entity Должность_Гражданство{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Гражданства <<FK>>
}

entity Должность_Регион{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Региона <<FK>>
}

entity Должность_Языки{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Языка <<FK>>
}

entity Должность_Опыт_работы{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Опыт работы <<FK>>
}

entity Должность_Тип_занятости{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Типа занятости <<FK>>
}

entity Должность_Образование{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Образования <<FK>>
}

Должность }|..|| Воронка
Должность ||..|{ Похожие_должности

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Гражданство
Гражданство ||..o{ Должность_Гражданство

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Регион
Регион ||..o{ Должность_Регион

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Образование
Образование ||..o{ Должность_Образование

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Языки
Языки ||..o{ Должность_Языки

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Опыт_работы
"Опыт работы" ||..o{ Должность_Опыт_работы

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Тип_занятости
"Тип занятости" ||..o{ Должность_Тип_занятости
@enduml
```

How can I control the placement of classes on the canvas? How can I set the padding between notations?

**I don't know what the detailes I need to add to submit post**

[image: ER-Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

With complicated diagrams, there are not a lot of options.

I tried adding some `Padding` with `polylines` and hiding the `empty members`. Then I forced some associations to be `up` direction to avoid overlapping:

```
@startuml
skinparam Padding 5
' hide the spot
hide circle

hide empty members

skinparam linetype polyline

entity Воронка{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity Должность{
  ID <<PK>>
  Код должности
  Наименование
  ID Воронки <<FK, UNIQUE>>
}

entity Гражданство{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity Регион{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity Образование{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity Языки{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity "Опыт работы"{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование
}

entity "Тип занятости"{
  ID <<PK>>
  Наименование 
}

entity Похожие_должности{
  ID Должности
  ID Похожей должности
}

entity Должность_Гражданство{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Гражданства <<FK>>
}

entity Должность_Регион{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Региона <<FK>>
}

entity Должность_Языки{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Языка <<FK>>
}

entity Должность_Опыт_работы{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Опыт работы <<FK>>
}

entity Должность_Тип_занятости{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Типа занятости <<FK>>
}

entity Должность_Образование{
  ID Должности <<FK>>
  ID Образования <<FK>>
}

Должность }|..|| Воронка
Должность ||..|{ Похожие_должности

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Гражданство
Гражданство ||.up.o{ Должность_Гражданство

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Регион
Регион ||.up.o{ Должность_Регион

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Образование
Образование ||.up.o{ Должность_Образование

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Языки
Языки ||.up.o{ Должность_Языки

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Опыт_работы
"Опыт работы" ||.up.o{ Должность_Опыт_работы

Должность ||..o{ Должность_Тип_занятости
"Тип занятости" ||.up.o{ Должность_Тип_занятости
@enduml
```

[image]